# Will ubuntu alter my other partitions on my PC

Tags: partitioning, system-installation

I have a compaq presario cq61-324CA. It is 4 years old and very slow on windows 7. I want to install ubuntu on it. I tried it out on the live cd and it is great! So I click install. Question If I install ubuntu will it delete other partitions like my recovery drive and my system and hp-tools drive it came with? Or will it just touch my C: Drive?

Comment: It depends. It may delete a partition if you tell it to, and it may refuse to install in case there are 4 primary partitions already. ... but it's hard to tell without knowing the current partition layout, your level of experties, and exactly what you will do. In short, the question is somewhat on the vague side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it deals with the entire disk and all partitions, try opening gparted while inside the live environment and resizing the windows 7 partition, then open the installer, and on the prompt where is asks if you want to erase disk and use entire disk for ubuntu, or install alongside, select "something else", go get a cup of coffee, then select the partition in the list that says "free space" and corresponds in name to the empty area on the diagram, click the change button, select "exxt4", "format" and use as "/", then just follow the prompts

Comment: What if I want to want to delete windows altogether instead of dual-booting it?

Comment: then select erase entire disk, a word of warning though, that will delete the windows recovery partition

Comment: or just open gparted and delete the windows partition, then continue with the given answer

Comment: it's nice to see someone show an interest, welcome to Linux!

Comment: If I want to dual boot will I have to create a swap partition too and can I allocate all the space on the partition to the / and swap if I need it?

Comment: swap really doesn't need to be that big, maybe 4gb on a device with 2gb of ram, on anything larger than 4 it should be the size of the ram

Comment: But can I allocate let's say 4GB to swap and the rest to /?

Comment: correct, depending on your ram 4gb should be enough

Answer (score 0):

To avoid having problems:

1. BACKUP YOUR IMPORTANT FILES! You never know what might happen (power failure, etc.)
2. For the safest of ways, in Windows, resize the windows partition leaving 50Gb free (just a guideline). Alternatively resize the Windows partition in step 5 below.
3. Launch the Installer
4. Choose "something else" option
5. In gparted create two partitions: a big one (all the freed up space - 4Gb) and choose ext4 and mount point `/`, and a small one (4Gb Swap)
6. This should leave your windows and recovery partitions intact.
7. Enjoy Ubuntu.